# Where does the Id part of a User field come from?

Tags: 2013, web-services, user

I am using SP web services (usergroup.asmx.GetUserCollectionFromSite()) to get the user IDs of users that I am programmatically adding to a usermulti field in a list.

Apparently this is not the user ID that is used in the User field as it ends up mapping to a different user.

**Example:**

> My ID from GetUserCollectionFromSite() is 26.
>   If I programmatically look at a list with my username in it, it is: `9;#My.UserName`

Where does the ID part of the User Field come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SPFieldUserValue` is inherited from `SPFieldLookupValu`e. So there is a lookup list. It is hidden user information list. You can get it from `SPWeb.SiteUserInfoList` or from /_catalogs/users/simple.aspx